# Order by NULL values with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
id            description status   login
XWPggD        bbbbbbbb    1        js
0JIERf        test1       1        js
0gd2x0        nothing     NULL     js
bSIUIu        dev         NULL     bob
0BNh27        hello       1        js
2TYXjd        down        NULL     inge
axE1m5        bobby       NULL     bob
1iSlQM        qwe         0        js
9dPjoP        descr       NULL     inge
```

I'm trying to sort the output by status(null values at the bottom) and then by login.
But I also want the login values, where the status is NULL to be ordered correctly, so that it looks like:

```
id            description status   login
XWPggD        bbbbbbbb    1        js
0JIERf        test1       1        js
0BNh27        hello       1        js
1iSlQM        qwe         0        js
axE1m5        bobby       NULL     bob
bSIUIu        dev         NULL     bob
9dPjoP        descr       NULL     inge
2TYXjd        down        NULL     inge
0gd2x0        nothing     NULL     js
```

But when I try something like:

```
SELECT id, description, status, login FROM dev
ORDER BY isnull(status) ASC, isnull(login) ASC;
```

I always get a weird loginorder where status values are NULL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why so complicated answers ...

```
SELECT id, description, status, login FROM dev
ORDER BY status IS NULL, status DESC, login IS NULL, login DESC
```

Comment: Works perfect and is simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id, description, status, login FROM dev
ORDER BY (Case when status is null then -1 Else status End ) Desc,
(Case when login is null then -1 Else 1 End ) Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `colaesce` function as below

```
SELECT id, description, status, login 
FROM dev
ORDER BY COALESCE(status,-1) ASC, COALESCE(login,-1) ASC
```

Comment: why you check login for null?

Comment: hmm nice hawk eyes gud